# Buttons in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, button

Currently I am trying to make the following a button on my WordPress blog. It is an automatic link that gets that class whenever it is posted but I just can't seem to make it work.

```
<div class="kpg-title">
<a href="/recentphotos/?album=Photosagain">photosagain</a>
</div>
```

This is the link to the 
[CSS](http://hiddenbrookstudio.com/recentphotos/wp-content/plugins/kpicasa-gallery-php4mod/kpicasa_gallery.css)

Any help would be greatly appreciated I am trying to use these [buttons](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/04/24/5-different-tutorials-of-creating-dynamic-css-round-corners-link-buttons/)

Comment: What's not working about it? What does it *currently* do?

Comment: A link to an example would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 styles in the CSS that affect the mark up. Neither of them are going to create the effect you are looking for. Check your class name.

```
table#kpg-albums td div.kpg-title a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

div#kpg-album-description div#kpg-title {
    font-weight: normal;

}
```